# Struggling with SQL Joins MIN/MAX

Tags: sql, join, mysqli, mariadb

I am really struggling with SQL, it just feels terribly foreign to me having come from C based languages.

I have two SQL tables.  One is called 'person' and holds fields for `IDNumber INT, FirstName VARCHAR, LastName VARCHAR`.  The other is called 'donations' and has fields for `IDNumber INT and DollarsRaised INT`. The donations IDNumber field is linked to the person IDNumber using a foreign key relationship.

I am trying to join the tables and to use MIN/MAX to display the members who have have raised the most and least dollars, but my textbook chose to use examples with some serious excess in the commands so I can't break down the syntax.  This is the closest I have gotten:

```
SELECT CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS Name,
   MAX(DollarsRaised) AS 'Highest Earner'
FROM donations
   JOIN person USING(IDNumber);
```

When doing this, it returns the name from the first entry in the person table every time rather than actually pulling the person who had the lowest value in dollarsraised.  The same is true if I use the MIN function.  I am assuming I need a GROUP BY statement or something along those lines, but am unsure of how to apply it correctly.

Comment: Your question says you have two tables named person and donations, what is donationlist ?

Comment: That's a typo, donationlist is donations, I renamed it

Comment: I work in SQL Server so I am not familiar with the SQL syntax you are using here, but I would do something like using a subquery to select the max donation value, then use it in a where clause to select the person who donated that amount. And then do the same design but using MIN

Comment: The syntax is MariaDB, I think I understand what you are saying though, gonna try tinkering with it some more.

Comment: So something like the following,                                                                                 SELECT CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS Name, DollarsRaised                        WHERE DollarsRaised =                                                                                           (Subquery)                                                                                                                      Subquery = SELECT MAX(DollarsRaised) FROM donations

Comment: Will the donations table have one row per person, or many rows per person?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this relationship is 1:M and you need the total. Here's a query to look at:

```
select *
from
    person p inner join 
    (select IDNumber, sum(DollarsRaised) as TotalDollarsRaised from donations) d
        on d.IDNumber = p.IDNumber
```

If you really just need the top, here's the old standard SQL approach. Note that it can return more than one row because of ties:

```
select * from person p inner join donations d on d.IDNumber = p.IDNumber
where DollarsRaised = (select max(DollarsRaised) from donations)
```

A way to get both min and max together is with a union:

```
select * from person p inner join donations d on d.IDNumber = p.IDNumber
where DollarsRaised = (select max(DollarsRaised) from donations)
union
select * from person p inner join donations d on d.IDNumber = p.IDNumber
where DollarsRaised = (select min(DollarsRaised) from donations)
order by DollarsRaised;
```

Supposing there was actually a tie for min and max the union (without `all`) would remove duplicate rows.

The problem you encountered with the wrong name being displayed is a MySQL oddity that allows you to reference a non-aggregated column where you shouldn't be able to do that. Many other platforms with give you an error instead.

Comment: The 'Old Standard SQL' approach got me what I needed with a syntax that I grasped easily. This is just an intro class, and we are doing everything via command line, it's all really basic. My final assignment is due tonight and this was holding me up, thank you SO much.

Comment: Is there a way I could pull both the MIN and MAX on two separate lines in a single query?

Comment: @RadHatter That's what the `union` query would accomplish. I believe that's what you're asking for. You could use `union all` to cover the case where min and max are equal but you still need separate rows.

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel behind in this course, but I think you have given me my first solid example of why I would use union vs join.  Thank you SO much, I just completed the 3 queries I needed for my assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT firstname + ' ' + lastname AS Name,
MAX(DollarsRaised) AS 'Highest Earner'
FROM donations  as d 
INNER JOIN persons as p on p.IDNumber = d.IDNumber
GROUP BY firstname + ' ' + lastname
ORDER BY MAX(DollarsRaised) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume there can be more than one donation per person in the donations table, meaning you first need to sum the donations for each person, and then show the person with the top dollar amount. The following would work for that:

```
SELECT p.IDNumber, p.FirstName, p.LastName,
SUM(d.DollarsRaised) AS DollarsRaised
FROM person p
INNER JOIN donations d
ON p.IDNumber = d.IDNumber
GROUP BY p.IDNumber, p.FirstName, p.LastName
ORDER BY DollarsRaised DESC
LIMIT 1
```